# @FindAll Is Kind of Slow When Trying to Locate Multiple Elements

Tags: java, performance, selenium, findall

I have a page that is localized and the "Create Account" WebElement can be English, Chinese or Japanese. I am using Selenium, Java and TestNG framework to run a test to click on this element. However, the slow performance when using this @FindAll to identify the page makes me wonder if there are any better way to do this.

The element from Inspect element while "English" locale is selected:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <a translate="create-account" class="pointer ng-scope" ng-click="vm.createAccount()">Create Account</a>
    </div>
```

My FindAll declaration:

```
@FindAll({
    @FindBy(linkText="Create Account"),
    @FindBy(linkText="创建账号"),
    @FindBy(linkText="アカウントを作成")
})
private List<WebElement> createAccount;
```

As a baseline to compare, if I use the @FindAll above, it takes about 15 seconds before Webdriver clicks on the link. If I use just @FindBy, it takes about 2-3 seconds. However, @FindBy does not work for me as I need to be able to locate the correct locale to click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single css selector like:
`a[ng-click*='createAccount']`

Or one of the xpaths:

```
//a[contains(@ng-click, 'createAccount')]
//a[contains(text(), 'Create Account') or contains(text(), '创建账号') or contains(text(), 'アカウントを作成')]
```

For css if you pass part of the attribute value then it should be `[@attributeName*='part_of_attribute_value']`
Please take a look here to view a basic list of css rules [w3schools css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I like the language agnostic approach of the first one. The last one is starting to get unwieldy and is only going to get worse as they add more languages.

Comment: Yes, is a good approach, when using texts the only advantage is that you are also testing the translation but at a stability and slight performance cost.You can accept the answer if is ok.

Comment: Thanks @lauda. I tried your css selector but somehow it still did not work. However your answer gave me another idea so I tried `code`  @FindBy (css="a.pointer.ng-scope")
 private WebElement CreateAccount; and that worked for me. I am wondering why `code` @FindBy (css="a[ng-click='createAccount']")
 private WebElement CreateAccount; did not work.

Comment: It didn't work because is partially incorrect. It should be a[ng-click*='createAccount']

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @lauda for helping out and the link to w3 css selectors.
I actually found two more ways that I can identify this link using css:

```
@FindBy(css="a[translate='create-account']")
private WebElement CreateAccount;
```

and

```
@FindBy (css="a.pointer.ng-scope")
private WebElement CreateAccount;
```

However, not sure why the original solution that lauda posted did not work for me though.

```
a[ng-click*='createAccount']
```